# Referencing Windows Azure Mobile Services in brand new Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, azure-mobile-services

I have created a brand new Windows Phone 8 application. I tried going to NuGet to include WindowsAzure.MobileServices. However, I received an error stating that I cannot reference System.Runtime.

I'm trying to include the current pre-release version as the 0.2 "stable" version doesn't work with Windows Phone.

Comment: Weird, I used the azure services many times before and I just double checked. I can include both stable and pre-release mobile azure services with no problems. You may have another problem that is causing this.

Comment: With Windows Phone 7 or Windows Phone 8?

Comment: My scenario can be reporduced. I'm working on solving it right now with someone from the NuGet team. I'll keep this posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were able to reproduce this and have filed a bug [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/issues/82) to investigate. You can see the progress of our investigation there.

Comment: I'll keep you posted on my progress.

Comment: Yavor solved my issue. Just so everyone on SO knows how he solved it, I had to update to NuGet 2.5 from 2.0. To do so, I also had to update my VS Phone Express to Update 2.